# Quick question about relation between Nullspace and Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question about a note given in a linear algebra textbook. It is just given as a remark, with no proof or explanation so I want to make sure I understand it correctly.

First, it gives the definition of the eigenspace of A to be, The set, $$E_{\lambda}=\{{v \in \mathbb R^n : Av= \lambda v}\}$$

and it then notes, from this we can see that because $E_{0}=N(A)$, this $\rightarrow$ a matrix is singular if and only if $\lambda=0$  is an eigenvalue.

But I am still a little confused. If I am recalling correctly, a  transformation is singular if there exists a $v  \neq 0$ for which $T(v)=0$

I guess in this case it is in regard to if  a matrix is invertible or not?
I think I may be getting confused between the two differences ( if there is one) and the differences between talking about just A and a transformation in general.

Anyone have any advice /explanations for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is singular, as you recalled, if there exists a $v\neq 0$ for which $Av=0=0\cdot v$. This shows it is the same as saying $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $0$. Thus 
$$A\enspace\text{singular}\iff \ker A \neq\{0\}\iff 0\enspace\text{is an eigenvalue for}\enspace A.$$

Comment: I see, is this because v=0 cannot be an eigenvector itself?

Comment: Yes. If $v=0$ was accepted as an eigenvector, any value would be an eigenvalue. (For a similar reason, $1$ is not accepted as a prime number).